# css position guide

Tags: html, css

In my work,I often use the css to make the page layout,however I found that I can not make it well beacuse of the css position.

I know the float/absolute/releative and etc.

But when I use them I often can not get what I wanted. Expecially when I use the nested layout,for example,using a absoluted position element within a float element and etc.

I have read the w3cschool tutorial,but I also can not exactly sure I understand it.

So I wonder if there is any detailed css guide? Or some common rules when I layout the element?

Comment: Not really the answer, but. You can absolutely position an element inside a floating element by giving the floating element a position:relative. The absolute positioned elements inside it will be positioned relative to the floating one, not to the window.

Comment: ++++. I have never heard that I can set the floating element with the releative position before you tell me. So I wonder if you can provide some guide which I can learn myself?

Comment: Well, there's always the spec: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/ :]

Answer (score 2):

I was also always looking for a definitive guide to css, but never found it. I think the best way to learn how css works and really understand it, is to look things up in a good reference and read it very carefully.
I think the Mozilla Developer Network is great, and they have a nice [css reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference).

Reading articles on websites like [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) is also a good way to get your head around some of the more advanced or complicated concepts. Their [article on floats](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/) has helped me in particular.

Answer (score 1):

I find Sitepoint's reference to be fairly useful: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css. I also second @Basil's recommendations of MDN and Smashing Magazine. [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/), while not really a reference site per se, is also a good place to find tutorials or informative articles: http://www.alistapart.com/topics/topic/css/.